# Slack - sharing screen - black screen

Tags: debian, slack-desktop

I am using debian 10 ... slack desktop Production 4.9.1 64-bit

I am getting a black screen when I tried to share in screen in a call.

I am getting this in the log:

```
[09/30/20, 16:41:14:528] info: [SCREENS] (T359LF935) Available screens:
-- | ----- | ------ | - | --- | ----------- | --------
id | width | height | x | y   | scaleFactor | rotation
-- | ----- | ------ | - | --- | ----------- | --------
33 | 1920  | 1080   | 0 | 0   | 2           | 0       
35 | 960   | 539    | 0 | 252 | 2           | 0       

[09/30/20, 16:41:14:598] error: SCREENS (T359LF935) Could not find matching display for 
screen 0 with id  
[09/30/20, 16:41:14:604] error: SCREENS (T359LF935) Could not find matching display for screen 1 with id
```

any help ?

Comment: Try disabling compositing.

Comment: I am using gnome 3 ... how I do that ?

Comment: google.com/search?q=gnome+3+disable+compositing

Comment: I found a working solution on this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1270710/black-screen-during-screen-share-in-ubuntu-18-04